# (x < 8) returns false when x = -3 (double)

Tags: c, if-statement, double

Code reads as follows:

```
if (chan->sampcnt < 8)
{
    *data = 0;
    return;
}
```

`chan` contains a pointer to a valid structure.  In the debugger, the value listed for `` `chan->sampcnt `` is `-3`.  Somehow it does not resolve the conditional as false and execute the code in the if statement's scope.  This is only the case very rarely, but it constitutes a major bug.

`sampcnt`'s default value, `-3`, is run through this conditional many times.  It almost always resolves correctly, but when it does not things get ugly fast.  What the heck is happening?  I am at a loss for words.  I have never encountered anything like this before.  Thanks in advance.

Update (to encourage reopening):

```
struct channel_struct
{
    channel_struct()
    {}
    u32 num;
   u8 vol;
   u8 datashift;
   u8 hold;
   u8 pan;
   u8 waveduty;
   u8 repeat;
   u8 format;
   u8 keyon;
   u8 status;
   u32 addr;
   u16 timer;
   u16 loopstart;
   u32 length;
   u32 totlength;
   double double_totlength_shifted;
   double sampcnt;
   double sampinc;
   // ADPCM specific
   u32 lastsampcnt;
   s16 pcm16b, pcm16b_last;
   s16 loop_pcm16b;
   int index;
   int loop_index;
   u16 x;
   s16 psgnoise_last;
};
```

This is a multi-threaded application.  I am not familiar with all the code as it is a large, complex project.  I have suspected sampcnt being changed in another thread, but when the bug occurs it demonstrates a shocking amount of regularity.  This makes me lean away from some sort of atomicity hiccup; however, it is still a consideration.  I have yet to identify code that modifies `chan->sampcnt` being run in another thread, but it could be out there.

Just to be clear.  `sampcnt` is of type double and I am sure.  It is declared as double and the debugger lists it as double.  Also, chan is a pointer to type `struct channel_struct`.

Comment: We need to see the definition of the structure type `chan` has. It would also be helpful to know some further details about your program, like whether it's multi-threaded, what the surrounding code is doing, etc. I wonder if you're violating the aliasing rules and accessing the object with an overlaid object of different type...

Comment: specifically, what type is sampcnt?

Comment: Short of OP adding more information, I'm leaning towards supporting the vote to close...

Comment: Similar oddities can occur when you compare unsigned and signed integers. For example: `unsigned lhs = -3; int rhs = 8; if (lhs < rhs) ...` will evaluate the condition as false (0), which is admittedly counterintuitive. Your title implies that it's of type `double`, though. Is that what you meant, and are you *sure* about it?

Comment: Unless there is a bug in the debugger/compiler/hardware (a possibility which I seriously doubt), then `sampcnt` is a double.

Comment: I added another block of code.  I copy and pasted the if block I posted above and pasted it below itself.  I replaced the `*data=0;` line with `printf("first conditional skipped with value: %d\n",chan->sampcnt);`.  There are only two or three possibilities I can think of under which this code block should be executed.  1. Atomicity problems 2. Compiler/OS bug (seems unlikely) 3. Third-party invasion of the programs virtual address space (hardware defect/damage, software ... this also seems unlikely).   For the record, I am pretty peeved that this was closed prematurely.

Comment: "I am pretty peeved that this was closed prematurely" -- Good luck with that.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that you are occasionally overwriting chan->sampcnt, so that it isn't really -3 when it fails ... this is a common problem, especially if chan points to malloced memory. You really haven't given nearly enough info, nor done enough debugging. You could, for instance, save the value of chan->sampcnt in a global variable before doing the test, and then when things go bad check that value to see if it's really what you expected it to be. The last thing you should do is assume that there's a bug in compiler or the hardware ... it's almost certainly in your program.

Comment: _The last thing you should do is assume that there's a bug in compiler or the hardware ... it's almost certainly in your program._

This.

Comment: I agree that the supposedly unchanging value is probably getting clobbered by a wild pointer. When I have to track down that kind of bug, I use a watchpoint in gdb. Set a breakpoint on the comparison, and the first time it gets there, check the value. If the value is correct (and not supposed to change from now on), set a watchpoint on it and continue.

Comment: Not to be rude, but your comment is filled with assumptions.  I have not supplied enough information, with that I agree; however, I have been doing many of the things you suggest(e.g. I check the value of sampcnt each time the bug occurs).  I am not assuming it is in the compiler or hardware.  I am just confused and not sure how best to proceed.  I was hoping that there was some idiosyncrasy of the use of doubles in comparisons that I had never run into before.  I find it difficult to believe that -3 is able to selectively pass/fail the conditional.

Comment: "Not to be rude" -- You're being that and a lot worse. Good luck ever getting any help from SO. "but your comment is filled with assumptions." -- There are no assumptions in my answer. "I was hoping that there was some idiosyncrasy of the use of doubles in comparisons that I had never run into before" -- There isn't. "I find it difficult to believe that -3 is able to selectively pass/fail the conditional." -- You're the one making assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting it to the following form should give the compiler a fighting chance to point out the problem.

```
double toTest = chan->sampcnt;
if ( toTest < 8)
{
    *data = 0;
    return;
}
```

Comment: not really an answer to the question...

Comment: This form is also more helpful when using a debugger because you can easily examine the value of chan->sampcnt before it's used in the comparison.

Comment: The compiler isn't going to point out anything, since the code is valid C.

Comment: I am using lldb as my debugger and I check `chan->sampcnt` after the comparison.  I am unsure how to catch it before the comparison as that particular block of code is run prolifically.  I have considered the use of condition breakpoints, but `sampcnt=-3` is run through the conditional correctly thousands of times between hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

```
int test = (int)chan->sampcnt;
if ( test < 8)
{
   *data = 0;
   return;
}
```

maybe `chan->sampcnt` is unsigned type

Comment: `chan->sampcnt` is of type double.  I have verified this in code and via the debugger at runtime. I have tried different types of floating-point casting to try and massage the code into working.